# Do connected, locally euclidean, Hausdorff, topological groups exist wihich are not second-countable?

Tags: manifolds, topological-groups

It is well-known that there exist connected, locally euclidean, Hausdorff, topological spaces which are not second-countable, i.e. the topology has no countable base. One example is the 2-dimensional Prüfer-manifold, see e.g. R.Nevanlinna: Uniformisierung (in German).
If we only replace topological space by topological group, does there still exist an example which is not second-countable? I do not see that the Prüfer-manifold could be endowed with a group structure which makes it a topological group, but someone might come up with a totally different construction. Or someone can prove that such a topological group does not exist? Or this is an already known result?

Comment: Hint: 1st countable Hausdorff topological groups are metrizable. Can you finish the proof now?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I could modulo the assertion that "1st countable Hausdorff topological groups are metrizable". Can you sketch a proof of this or give a reference to the literature?

Comment: It is Birkhoff-Kakutani theorem, you can find it in the book of Montgomery and Zippin.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, thanks for your decisive hints: So the overall result is: A topological group as asked in the title of my question does not exist, right?

Comment: Right..........